# Trouble turning my menu into a dropdown menu

Tags: html, css, menu

Just finished designing my first menu style left navigation bar. Is it possible to make this menu have a dropdown effect on hover without javascript? Most answers i found do not work for me since i probably used the wrong kind of code to build up a real menu.

In the example the categorie "Heren armbanden" is the main categorie. The 6 categories below it should dropdown when hover on "Heren armbanden".

Hopefully there is a way to make this work. Any suggestions are welcome!

Comment: JSfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/Lookinggoodtoday/bxeh6/

Comment: It would definitely be easiest to do this using Javascript.  Why are you opposed to any JS solutions?

Comment: Not opposed, it's just that i just started learning to use some code. Just css and html is already a lot. I want to save javascript for later since i need this navigation to work way faster than i could learn how to do some decent coding:)

Comment: If I were to post a JS-related solution to your problem, would you consider it?  Or are you looking for strictly css-based solutions?

Comment: Your JSFiddle is having a tough time loading.  Can you remove the dependencies to your live website?  I think that is slowing it down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you did say that you were looking for a pure-CSS solution, you said in the comments that you would not be opposed to a JS solution, which I took as a go-ahead for solving your problem using Javascript (in particular, jQuery).

First, I created a class `menu` that I used to surround your dropdown menu header and the menu contents.

```
<div class="menu">
    <div class="container25-a">
        <div class="links8">Heren armbanden</div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="heren-armbanden">
        <div class="container25-a">
            <div class="links4">Schakel armbanden</div>
        </div>
        <div class="container25-a">
            <div class="links4">Leren armbanden</div>
        </div>
        <div class="container25-a">
            <div class="links4">Stalen armbanden</div>
        </div>
        <div class="container25-a">
            <div class="links9">Rubberen armbanden</div>
        </div>
        <div class="container25-a">
            <div class="links4">Graveerbare armbanden</div>
        </div>
        <div class="container25-a">
            <div class="links4">Zilveren armbanden</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Next, I created a CSS selector property that hides the class `heren-armbanden` from view by default.

```
.heren-armbanden {
    display: none;
}
```

Finally, I used jQuery to add listeners to the `menu` class, and change the visibility of the `heren-armbanden` class when the mouse enters and leaves the menu class.

```
$('.menu').hover(function () {
    $('.heren-armbanden').show();
}, function () {
    $('.heren-armbanden').hide();
});
```

All in all, your solution looks like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/bxeh6/8/

EDIT:  As requested, here is how to perform these actions on click instead of on hover:

Add a different class or id to the link you want to click:

```
<div class="links8" id="nav">Heren armbanden</div>
```

Then, add an event to listen for the click:

```
$('#nav').click(function () {
    $('.heren-armbanden').toggle();
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/bxeh6/9/

Comment: Thank you for this solution, it works exactly like how i meant it to. I guess to install jquery and use this will be alot easier as to learn how to code a menu using <li> and <ul>. 1 more question: It will also be possible to do what u did above with hover but then on click? So the menu will drop down on click instead of on hover.

Comment: It would be wise to follow the HTML spec regardless of whether or not this particular solution works for you.  In other words, although this is a workaround that I came up with given the code you already have, any time you have a list of elements, using the appropriate tag `ul` or `ol` is preferable.  And yes, it is possible to do so on click as well.  I can edit my post to demonstrate that.

Comment: That would be great if you could demonstrate that aswell. And yes i agree using html like it's supposed to is something i should follow. However im already proud i came this far:)

Comment: Thanks for the edit. It works great this way. Now to try figure out how to implement the script part on my site and i can try and finish this navigation.

Comment: You don't necessarily **need** jQuery, that's just what I used.  I find that it is much easier to navigate the DOM using jQuery, and to be honest, I can't really write any javascript without putting a dollar sign in front of it :P.  As far as adding jQuery goes, you can just download the minified js file and link to it in your html file with script tags like so: `<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/js/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Trying to figure out first how to make the whole navigation funcional using your fiddle. Having several different drop down menu;s and make the items clickable. http://jsfiddle.net/Lookinggoodtoday/bxeh6/12/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58288/discussion-between-michael-parker-and-user3848889).

Answer (score 0):

I apologize that I cannot open your example from where I am currently at.  The key to making drop downs using CSS is the Display property in your styles.  For a pure CSS dropdown you would make the UL for the menu with

```
ul{Disply:none;}
```

and the

```
UL:hover{display:block;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Drop down navigations in CSS are actually very easy. However, you will need some alterations in your code.

The main issue with your code is the menu items with a downwards arrow (which I assume display the dropdown) have no relation to their dropdown counterpart. More specifically, the top-level menu item named `Heren sieraden` *does not contain* a relationship to the children item `Heren armbanden`. Furthermore, the `Schakel armbanden` element is not contained by `Heren armbanden`.

When I say "contained", I mean that within the markup the items are "on the same level" (siblings). CSS is not capable of relating objects in this manner. Instead, you need to nest them so that your CSS can look at the top elements first, see if you are hovering over them, and then hide their contained sub menus.

**In order for a pure CSS to work, you will need to restructure your code.**

Some other answers have already explained the `ul` and `li` solution that is very popular. It's popular for a reason - the `ul` element serves as the "menu", and the `li` elements serve as the "item". Below is an example:

(Redundant classes not shown)

```
ul.menu
  li.item
    a
  li
    a
    ul.sub-menu
      li.item
        a
      li
        a
  li
    a
```

Above, you have `ul.menu`. This is your main menu. The second `li` element contains a `ul.sub-menu`. This is your sub-menu (dropdown).

The main problem with your current code is that an `a:hover` selector is useless here. If you hover over a link, you imagine the sub-menu to appear, right? BUT when you hover out of the link, the sub menu would close. This is why you need to use the `ul > li > ul` structuring. You can use divs instead, but ul/li is more common.

The key is to not assign the `:hover` selector to the `a` element, but to the `li` element. This is because the `li` element contains **both the `a` and the `ul` elements**. So whether you hover over the link, or the sub menu, you are still hovering over the `li`.

And thus, to make your dropdown work, you want to use something like:

```
ul.menu li.item ul.sub-menu       { display: none;  }
ul.menu li.item:hover ul.sub-menu { display: block; }
/* note: these selectors can certainly be simplified */
```

Now your sub menu appears when you hover over the container.

Positioning your submenus is typically done by giving the `li.item` element a relative position (position: relative) and then giving the `ul.sub-menu` element an absolute position (position: absolute). That allows you to place your sub-menu below the menu item.

```
li.item { position: relative; }
ul.sub-menu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
}
```

The above CSS will position your sub menu at the bottom-left corner of the menu item it resides in. The sub menu will expand down and to the right.